# Multi Page website using Angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am creating a multi page website with Asp.net-MVC and Angular 2. In my application there are 3 pages : Login Page, Index Page and Contact Page.

There are two angular modules in the application:

- LoginModule
- IndexModule

There are 3 angular components in the application

- LoginComponent
- GraphComponent
- ContactComponent

How this application should work:

- Login Page use LoginModule. LoginModule use LoginComponent
- Index Page use IndexModule. IndexModule use GraphComponent and
  ContactComponet
- Contact Page also use IndexModule. ContactModule use only
  ContactComponent.

What are the Problem i am facing

- How can i bootstrap different Modules on different pages. That is, 
  On Login page i have to bootstrap LoginModule and on Index Page and
  Contact Page i have to bootstrap IndexModule.
- How to use include component conditionally in one module. Like i have
  to include GraphComponent and ContactComponent in IndexModule on
  Index page and Only ContactComponent in IndexModule on Contact page.

Please let me know if something is unclear here!!

Thanks!!

Comment: If I understand well your problem, you'd have to lazy load every module you described and then search into the router documentation to selectively load a module. But why do you want to do that ? Are you just looking for lazy loading ?

Comment: @Maxime: Thanks for the answer. I don't know anything about Lazy loading in angular 2. Can you please let me know that Lazy Loading resolves  both the problems or it will just fix the first problem?

Comment: Lazy loading allows you to load a **module** only when needed. For example, if you have an app with "contacts" and "emails". Let say that contacts should be loaded only when needed, then when you click on contacts link, your URL will be like "/contacts" and the router will see that contacts module is not loaded so it download it on the moment. I've made a basic demo here if you want to give a try and see some code : https://github.com/maxime1992/angular2-nrgx-demo/tree/lazy-loading

Comment: And to answer your question I think that it would solve your first problem. Your second problem is mostly a design problem. Modules are not meant to include one component and conditional another. My demo might help you to understand with contacts and email ;)